# Spring Cloud Dataflow with tasks based on Spring Boot 3 and Spring Batch 5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

We are migrating Spring Batch applications based on Spring Boot 2.7.x to Spring Boot 3.0.0. With that migration we noticed changes in versions from Spring Batch 4.3.7 to Spring Batch 5.0.0 and Spring Cloud dependencies from 2021.0.3 to 2022.0.0-RC2.

Spring Cloud Dataflow and the tasks share the same database and there is a difference in the schema that prevents the task from running successfully. An exception is thrown, caused by a missing column in the existing schema that was created by SCDF, i.e. in table `batch_step_execution` the column `create_time` is missing.

My understanding is, that the tables *should* be managed by SCDF using it's internal Flyway migration scripts, e.g. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/main/resources/schemas/postgresql

I was trying to just migrate to Spring Boot 3 and get things up and running again. But it did not work.
I tried then looking for a Spring Cloud Dataflow roadmap regarding the version trouble, but I could not found anything related to Spring Boot 3 or Spring Batch 5.

I only noticed that there is version SCDF 2.9.x that is not OSS-supported anymore, see https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow#support and there is hardly any information about SCDF 2.10 but it still seems to be on Spring Cloud dependencies 2021.

Is there plans for updating SCDF that enables it to run tasks based on Spring Boot 3 and Spring Batch 5? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for asking these questions.
SCDF is planning to release Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.10 in mid December. Currently SCDF only supports Spring Batch 4.x and Task 2.x.   After the release of 2.10 we will begin working on supporting Task 2.x and Task 3.x applications for both Batch 4.x and 5.x respectively.
You can track the progress on this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/5152